# Convert "3 - 4" to "03 - 04" with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a way to append zero to all numbers under 10.

Examples:

> `"3 - 4"` becomes `"03 - 04"`
>
> `"3 - 10"` becomes `"03 - 10"`
>
> `"1 - 7"` becomes `"01 - 07"`

and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: (...) and so far, you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression pattern in the following `preg_replace()` function, matches the single-digits (the single digits not having any digits before nor after themselves); and then, the function appends a leading `0` to the found matches:

```
<?php
$str = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15";
$result = preg_replace('~(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)~', '0$0', $str);
echo $result; // 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
?>
```

Comment: `~\b\d\b~` is a shorter regex and easier to understand.

Comment: @axiac If [that's](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30964939/2) enough for you, then use it; However, the updated pattern will also detect the single digits in `"x1-2"` and will change it to `"x01-02"` :)

Comment: It's enough for the strings specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
\b(\d)\b
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM7iZ9/1)**

Php code

```
$str = "3 - 4\n\n3 - 10\n\n1 - 7 ";  
$result = preg_replace('/\b(\d)\b/', "0$1", $str);
```

[image]